# What is difference between WordPress installed on shared hosting and WordPress hosting

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, shared-hosting

Just wanted to learn about shared hosting environment configuration.

There are many Hosting services providing WordPress hosting (example: http://www.hostgator.in/apps/wordpress-hosting and https://in.godaddy.com/hosting/wordpress-hosting)

In shared hosting we can anyway offer clients to install WordPress. But when we speak about specific WordPress hosting services, whats the difference? Do they configure some optimum settings for WordPress performance of this is just pre-install convenience.

I have people talking about that WordPress in WordPress hosting would perform better in traffic than WordPress in simple shared hosting.

Please share your knowledge with regards to the configuration of the shared hosting.

Answer (score 4):

WordPress on shared hosting assumes that the end user understands how to maintain a WordPress install.  The big things being updating WordPress, and even more importantly updating their WordPress plugins.

WordPress plugins are notorious for having security vulnerabilities and may result in the site being modified by a malicious party.  A hosted solution should be able to respond to these issues more quickly, and remove the malicious changes, and update and/or protect the plugins.

As well a hosted solution will likely have backup systems in place as well as being hosted on high availability infrastructure and caching layers for busy sites to mitigate load to keep the amount of CPU resources at a minimum, allowing busy sites to host a lot of traffic and slow traffic sites to have the CPU needed to render their site in a reasonable (milliseconds) amount of time.  These benefits come from the host knowing they are hosting WordPress and only WordPress, and thus can deploy specialised solutions.

On shared hosting one usually gets an Apache, with some random version of PHP that is decided to be good for most people, and access to a database.  If your application gets slammed you chew the CPU on the host and the host will likely throttle access to CPU resources rendering the site effectively offline.  This means that a hosted solution will usually be mostly impervious to a DDoS and a shared solution can be taken offline with modest resources.  As well, the end provider doesn't have a way to test everyone's website with updates they are going to apply, so sometimes the host may break some sites to perform updates to the installed PHP or other supporting application software.

Comment: Great inputs. Thank you for giving understanding on this.

Answer (score 1):

> "Wordpress **(or put any Webapp here)** hosting" simply means that the
>   Hosting Panel of the Provider has a "1 Click Installer" for the
>   Advertised Software and "Auto Update Functionality".

Concerning your Webapp Performance, the Web Hosting Panel for example Cpanel or Plesk have no influence on the performance of your Webapp.

Performance is set either through Hardware limitation, Vnode limitation or Hosting Panel limitation - which are set by your Hosting Provider with your Hosting Service Plan.

Answer (score 0):

Making a simple wordpress site/blog using https://wordpress.com/ should be the fastest way to get your site/blog idea up and running in no time. But, if you want more flexibility and control, even better performance(ex: caching, dns, cdn..) over your site I would suggest GoDaddy hosting and/or any reliable web hosting services.